# open another http connection in java

Tags: java

I tried to connect to a website, get some URL from it, and then connect to those URL, get some information. Here is my code.

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.nchmf.gov.vn/web/vi-VN/62/23/44/map/Default.aspx");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    String l;
    String Area;

    Pattern Province = Pattern.compile("Thị xã/T.Phố :");
    Pattern City = Pattern.compile("<option(.*?)ue=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</option>");


    while ((l=in.readLine())!=null) {
        Matcher ProvinceFound = Province.matcher(l);
        if (ProvinceFound.find()) {
            while((l=in.readLine())!=null
                  && !l.contains("</select></span>")){
                Matcher CityCode = City.matcher(l);
                if(CityCode.find()){
                    if(!"0".equals(CityCode.group(2))){
                        URL url1 = new URL("http://www.nchmf.gov.vn/web/vi-VN/62/23/44/map/Default.aspx");
                        URLConnection con1 = url1.openConnection();
                        BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con1.getInputStream()));

                        while((Area=in1.readLine())!=null){
                            System.out.println(Area);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result I get is nothing but empty lines. It still prints something if I put "System.out.println(l);" on the first connection, so I think the problem is the second connection.

Can anyone tell me what wrong in my code, thank you very much.

Comment: Follow standard Java naming conventions. Variables (Province, City, ProvinceFound...) should NOT start with upper case characters.

Comment: are you sure that the code is reaching the second connection? debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you can't read from the second URL because you are blocking on the first URL. Two suggestions:

1. Start a new Thread for every new URL you want to read
2. Read all the data in the first URL and add the links that your want to process to a List. Then when you finish reading the main URL you can read each of the other URL's one at a time.